# Why AWS RDS is showing exception - Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

Code -

```
private static String getDBInstanceTag(AmazonRDS amazonRDS, String dbInstanceIdentifier, String region, String tagKey) {

        log.info("Trying to fetch dbInstanceIdentifier - " + dbInstanceIdentifier + " in db instance region - " + region);
        String arn = String.format("arn:aws:rds:" + region + ":%s:db:%s",
                SyncJobConstants.AWSProperties.AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
                dbInstanceIdentifier);
        ListTagsForResourceResult tagsList = amazonRDS.listTagsForResource(
                new ListTagsForResourceRequest().withResourceName(arn));

        for(Tag tag : tagsList.getTagList()) {
            if(tagKey.equalsIgnoreCase(tag.getKey())) {
                return tag.getValue();
            }
        }

        throw new InternalProcessingException(tagKey + " is not present in given dbInstance - " + tagsList);
    }

    public static String getDBInstanceTag(String dbInstanceIdentifier, String tagKey) throws IOException {

        AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(
                RedshiftUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("AWSCredentials.properties"));
        AmazonRDS amazonRDS = new AmazonRDSClient(credentials);

        DBInstance dbInstance = new DBInstance();
        dbInstance.setDBInstanceIdentifier(dbInstanceIdentifier);

        for(String region : SyncJobConstants.AWSProperties.RDS_REGIONS) {
            try {
                return getDBInstanceTag(amazonRDS, dbInstanceIdentifier, region, tagKey);
            } catch (DBInstanceNotFoundException e) {
                log.info("dbInstanceIdentifier - " + dbInstanceIdentifier + " is not present in db instance region - " + region);
            } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
                if ( "AccessDenied".equals(e.getErrorCode()) ) {
                    log.info("dbInstanceIdentifier - " + dbInstanceIdentifier + " is not present in db instance region - " + region);
                } else {
                    throw new InternalProcessingException("Not able to fetch dbInstance details from RDS. DBInstanceId - " + dbInstanceIdentifier, e);
                }
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidRequestException("RDS endpoint details is not correct.");
    }
```

It is throwing error for some of the calls even though db instances is there. Error detail -

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The specified resource name does not match an RDS resource in this region. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: b0e01d56-36ca-11e6-8441-1968d9061f57)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.invoke(AmazonRDSClient.java:5197)
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.listTagsForResource(AmazonRDSClient.java:1997)
```

Can you please tell me what I am missing here ?

**Error meanings-**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html

**Update 2**

```
public static final List RDS_REGIONS = Arrays.asList("us-east-1",
                "us-west-1",
                "us-west-2",
                "eu-west-1",
                "eu-central-1",
                "ap-northeast-1",
                "ap-northeast-2",
                "ap-southeast-1",
                "ap-southeast-2",
                "sa-east-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a region related issue - Is your RDS instance located in region `US-EAST-1`? (that's the default region of Amazon SDK)

Log into Amazon web console and confirm the region. Set the correct region and try again.

Reference : [AWS Region Selection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-region-selection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I am sharing an idea that might help someone..

As it seems the user is using a [Java AWS SDK client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rds/AmazonRDSClient.html), he can use `describeDBInstances` on the

```
AmazonRDS amazonRDS = new AmazonRDSClient(credentials);
DescribeDBInstancesResult describeDBInstancesResult = amazonRDS.describeDBInstances();
```

then you can debug and look into the `describeDBInstancesResult` to make sure that DB is actually within the scope of current instantiated `amazonRDS` client.

if its not there, it might be that he using not passing the right region into the client.